# MFCC feature descriptors for audio classification using librosa

Tags: python, audio, machine-learning

I am trying to obtain single vector feature representations for audio files to use in a machine learning task (specifically, classification using a neural net). I have experience in computer vision and natural language processing, but I need some help getting up to speed with audio files.

There are a variety of feature descriptors for audio files out there, but it seems that MFCCs are used the most for audio classification tasks. My question is this: how do I take the MFCC representation for an audio file, which is usually a matrix (of coefficients, presumably), and turn it into a single feature vector? I am currently using [librosa](http://bmcfee.github.io/librosa/) for this.

I have a bunch of audio files, but they all vary in their shape:

```
for filename in os.listdir('data'):
    y, sr = librosa.load('data/' + filename)
    print filename, librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr=sr).shape

213493.ogg (20, 2375)
120093.ogg (20, 7506)
174576.ogg (20, 2482)
194439.ogg (20, 14)
107936.ogg (20, 2259)
```

What I would do as a CV person is quantize these coefficients by doing k-means and then use something like [scipy.cluster.vq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.vq.html#scipy.cluster.vq.vq) to get vectors of identical shape that I can use as input to my NN. Is this what you would do in the audio case as well, or are there different/better approaches to this problem?

Answer (score 17):

Check out [scikits.talkbox](http://scikits.appspot.com/talkbox). It has various functions that help you generate MFCC from audio files. Specifically you would wanna do something like this to generate MFCCs.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile
from scikits.talkbox.features import mfcc

sample_rate, X = scipy.io.wavfile.read("path/to/audio_file")
ceps, mspec, spec = mfcc(X)
np.save("cache_file_name", ceps) # cache results so that ML becomes fast
```

Then while doing ML, do something like:

```
X = []
ceps = np.load("cache_file_name")
num_ceps = len(ceps)
X.append(np.mean(ceps[int(num_ceps / 10):int(num_ceps * 9 / 10)], axis=0))
Vx = np.array(X)
# use Vx as input values vector for neural net, k-means, etc
```

I used this stuff when I was building an audio genre classification tool ( [genreXpose](https://github.com/jazdev/genreXpose)).

PS: One handy tool for audio conversion that I used was [PyDub](http://pydub.com/)

Comment: The way I understand it, mfcc features are a 2d array of the form (numFrames, numMFCCoeffiecients). That is each frame yields a list of MFCCs. The ceps variable seems to just be a 1d array of coefficients. Why is this so? Also what is the purpose of the X.append line? I'm really curious about this and i'd appreciate any light shed on the matter

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on the task. I would try kmeans, etc, but there are a lot of cases where that might not be helpful.

There's a few good examples of using [dynamic time warping with librosa](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/crawles/dtw/blob/master/Speech_Recognition_DTW.ipynb).

There's also the idea of using a sliding windows of a known shape, might be good too. Then you could consider the previous prediction and a transition probability matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, in audio classification literature, all audio files are truncated to the same length depending on the classification task (i.e., I'm working on fall detection devices, so I know that the audio files should not last longer than 1s since this is the expected duration of a fall event).

Then, for every audio file, you can extract MFCC coefficients for each frame and stack them together, generating the MFCC matrix for a given audio file. Since every audio file has the same length and we assume that all frames contain the same number of samples, all matrices will have the same size.

Comment: could you please share your code. i'm working on a similar task . would like to understand the approach